# I am able to load an wsdl file through curl .but not through SoapClient. I am not sure why?

Tags: php, web-services, curl, soap, wsdl

getting the below soap error

```
"SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from
'https://ics2wstest.ic3.com/commerce/1.x/transactionProcessor/CyberSource
Transaction_1.25.wsdl' : failed to load external entity 
"https://ics2wstest.ic3.com/commerce/1.x/transactionProcessor/CyberSourceTransaction_1.25.wsdl
```

This is the code:

```
<?php

     $opts = array(
          'ssl' => array('ciphers'=>'RC4-SHA', 'verify_peer'=>false,                  'verify_peer_name'=>false)
       );
        // SOAP 1.2 client
       $params = array ('encoding' => 'UTF-8', 'verifypeer' => false, 'verifyhost' => false, 'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2, 'trace' => 1, 'exceptions' =>  1, "connection_timeout" => 180, 'stream_context' => stream_context_create($opts)       );
    $url = "https://ics2wstest.ic3.com/commerce/1.x/transactionProcessor/CyberSourceTransaction_1.26.wsdl";

      try{
         $client = new SoapClient($url,$params );
         var_dump($client);
     }
     catch(SoapFault $fault) {
          echo '<br>'.$fault;
     }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this code to list functions:

```
$url = "https://ics2wstest.ic3.com/commerce/1.x/transactionProcessor/CyberSourceTransaction_1.26.wsdl";
$client = new SoapClient($url);
var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
```

and this gives one function:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(50) "ReplyMessage runTransaction(RequestMessage $input)"
}
```

Comment: thanks. I tried it. it works with one server and doesn't work with another server. It seems i have check the server config.